# See if any of a number of zip files contains any of the original files in a directory structure

Tags: files, zip, checksum, deduplication, rmlint

I have a pretty hard problem here.

I have a photo library with a lot of photos in it in various folders.

I then started using Google Photos for my photos, I put those originals into Google Photos, and used it for 5+ years.

Now I want to move away from Google Photos.  I have done a Google Takeout of all my photos, and downloaded all the Zip files, ~1.5TB worth of them (150 x ~10GB files).

Now I want to keep my original directory structure, and delete all the files that are duplicated in Google Photos.   After this operation, I basically want to have two directories left over each with unique files in them.  I can then merge this by hand later.

I have started extracting all the files and then I will run `rmlint` to detect duplicates and purge from Google Drive.  The problem is I don't have enough space to maneuvre all this around, so I have to extract say 30 archives, then run `rmlint`, purge, extract another 30, run `rmlint` again, purge, etc.  This rescans my original files over and over, and it's going to take a really long time to do.  I already use the `--xattr` flag for rmlint to try and speed up subsequent runs. See appendix for full `rmlint` command.

How can I do this WITHOUT having to first extract all the archives? Is there a way to just use the file checksums in the zip files and compare to those?

Thanks!

Appendix

```
rmlint \
        --xattr \
        -o sh:rmlint-photos.sh \
        -o json:rmlint-photos.json \
        --progress \
        --match-basename \
        --keep-all-tagged \
        --must-match-tagged \
        "/mnt/f/GoogleTakeout/" \
        // \
        "/mnt/e/My Documents/Pictures/" \
```

Comment: Your workflow is badly designed. You should use `zip` to list the contents of each `.zip` file, select the desired files, and, in a second pass, have `zip` extract only those files. `rmlint` should not be needed. Rather than cleaning up junk, don't make junk in the first place. Read `man hardlinks`.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh or bash and with libarchive's `bsdtar` and GNU `tar`, you could do something like:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.zip' -type f -print0 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' archive; do
    bsdtar -cf - "@$archive" |
      ARCHIVE=$archive tar -xf - --to-command='
        case $TAR_FILETYPE$TAR_FILENAME in
          (f*.jpg | f*.JPG)
            sha1sum | {
              IFS= read -r sum rest &&
                printf "%s\n" "$sum:$ARCHIVE:$TAR_FILENAME"
            }
        esac' > sums.txt
```

(assuming none of the archive paths nor members contain newline nor `:` characters) to get a list of `<checksum>:<archive>:<file-in-archive>` for each of the archives (will take a while as it runs one `sha1sum` per image).

Then, you could extract only one file for each unique checksum with something like:

```
perl -F: -slane '
  ($sum, $archive, $file) = @F;
  if (!$seen{$sum}++) {
    push @{$files{$archive}}, $file;
  }
  END {
    for $archive (keys %files) {
      open EXTRACT, "|-", "bsdtar", "-C", $dest, "-T", "/dev/stdin", "-xvnf", $archive;
      for (@{$files{$archive}}) {
        s/[][?*\\]/\\$&/g; # escape wildcards
        print EXTRACT;
      }
    }
  }' -- -dest='/mnt/e/My Documents/Pictures/' sums.txt
```

(you may want to add some more error handling).

It would likely be more efficient to do both checksum and extracting in `perl` at the same time though:

```
(LC_ALL=C find "$PWD" -name '*.zip' -type f -print0 | {
  cd '/mnt/e/My Documents/Pictures' &&
    perl -MArchive::Zip -MDigest::SHA=sha1 -0lne '
      my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
      if ($zip->read($_) == AZ_OK) {
        for $member ($zip->membersMatching(".*\.jpe?g")) {
          $zip->extractMember($member)
            unless (!$seen{sha1(zip->contents($member))}++);
        }
      }'
)
```

(warning: this is all untested).

Comment: +1.  The `%seen` hash in the perl part of the one-liners could keep the pathname of the 1st seen sha1 instead of a counter, then it could use `link(old,new)` to make a hard-link for dupes.  Another enhancement for the last version would be to allow it to be re-run by saving the %seen hash (using Data::Dump or some other serialisation module) on exit, and load it when it first starts up. Maybe use a second hash with key=filename, val=sha1.  Also, the `:` separated format in the two stage version could use NUL instead, and the perl part could read in three NUL-separated records at a time.